# SQL ORACLE order by numbers ans strings

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to use:

```
select * from list order by  id;
select * from list order by  LPAD(id, 4);
```

But it not working.

I have this list  in oracle table :

```
id (varchar2)
-----------
123
124
125
126
toto
bobo
koko
201
169
```

So I need a result like this:

```
123
124
125
126
169
201
bobo
koko
toto
```

Comment: What if you have mixed numbers and letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add in the `ORDER BY` clause an additional expression that checks whether the value contains number only (in which case it should be given the priority), like:

```
SELECT *
FROM list
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(id, '^[0-9]*$') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    id
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
order by (case when regexp_like(id, '^[0-9]+$')
               then to_number(id)
          end) asc nulls last,
         id
```

This will handle numeric ids numerically, even if they are not all the same length.